# getting the user click inputs in openlayers and store in postgis

Tags: gis, openlayers, postgis, geoserver

i am developing a web based application for showing the public vehicle routes using GeoServer, PostGIS and OpenLayers. what i need to do is let the user define a route by clicking on the main bus stop nodes on the map and i need to store those nodes of the route in my database. till now i have displayed the map and taken the user click inputs and got the coordinates where the user clicked. so now my problem is how to store those coordinate values in my database. i think this is where WFS-T comes in to transact the data between geoserver and the openlayers but i am not sure about it. am i suppose to use GML/KML to trasact the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right. You can use WFS-T to edit data in PostGIS via Geoserver. [Here's an example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wfs-protocol-transactions.html) of how it works.